# Rewriting code with continuations

Tags: haskell, continuations, continuation-passing

I have some code that evaluates primitive programs. Program is a list of statements (expression, block, return statement). Result of evaluation is last evaluated expression. Also evaluator should properly treat `return` statement (i.e. stop evaluation after first occurrence of `return`).

To implement this logic I pass special callback function (`NextStep`) which make next evaluating step after current statement. I don't call next step when handling return statement:

```
data Statement = 
      Expr Int
    | Block [Statement]
    | Return Int
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Value = 
      Undefined
    | Value Int
    deriving (Show, Eq)

type NextStep = Value -> Value

evalStmt :: Statement -> NextStep -> Value
evalStmt (Expr val) next = 
    let res = Value val
    in next res
evalStmt (Block stmts) next = evalBlock stmts next
evalStmt (Return val) next = Value val

evalBlock :: [Statement] -> NextStep -> Value
evalBlock [] next = next Undefined
evalBlock [st] next = evalStmt st next
evalBlock (st:rest) next = evalStmt st $ \ _ -> evalBlock rest next

evalProgram stmts = evalBlock stmts id

prog1 = [Expr 1, Block [Return 3, Expr 2], Expr 4] 
evalProg1 = evalProgram prog1 -- result will be Value 3
```

The question is how can I rewrite this code with continuation monad? I want to get rid of explicitly passed `NextStep` callback in `evalStmt` and `evalBlock` functions. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The translation is fairly mechanical.

Keep in mind that in the continuation monad, `return` feeds the value into the continuation.

```
evalStmt :: Statement -> Cont Value Value
evalStmt (Expr val) = 
    let res = Value val
    in return res
evalStmt (Block stmts) = evalBlock stmts
evalStmt (Return val) = cont $ \_ -> Value val

evalBlock :: [Statement] -> Cont Value Value
evalBlock [] = return Undefined
evalBlock [st] = evalStmt st
evalBlock (st:rest) = evalStmt st >> evalBlock rest

evalProgram :: [Statement] -> Value
evalProgram stmts = runCont (evalBlock stmts) id
```

And to simulate early returns, we just ignore the continuation given to `Return val` and just return the value we have.

Comment: The monad instance for `Cont` is defined to chain in precisely that way, so that *should* simply be equivalent to `evalBlock (st:rest) = evalStmt st >> evalBlock rest`